# MySQL value includes links, having trouble changing the text into a hyperlink (my title sucks)

Tags: php, regex, text-parsing

I'm sorry if this has been asked, but I can't really find a solution that works.  I am working on a message board system and it's done and working, but I need to dumb it down, I currently have it set up to strip everything that will break the sql and such but allows strong, em, img, and a.  My issue is that if I use tags it works fine, but people sometimes don't know how to use that, so instead of me having to display text explaining it, I just want php to fix it for me.  So users would be able to cut and paste an address and then input text and have more addresses if they need them and then submit the form.  When it is then displayed I want the hyperlinks to work.  Right now if I use tags it works fine, but if I don't use tags it just spits out the normal text.

I've looked all over the place and nothing works.  The most I had happen was that the post didn't show up at all.  If there is a different language to do this in easier I'm willing to work with it, but right now I'm focusing on PHP and MySQL to get this done.  I am willing to post the code if it's needed, but I didn't want to flood this post with a lot of data that wouldn't really help.  I just need it to search the body data find the link turn it into a link and then spit it out with everything around it.

To clear somethings up, I am using methods which are within an includes folder.  Each normal page only has a small bit of code that pertains to what I need it to do.  So the forum.php has no design really, but pulls a header file and footer file which has all of the design and static content that doesn't change from page to page.  Now the read.php file pulls all of the files in the includes folder and applies them if needed.  So the code that I used:

```
public static function url_to_link($text) {
        // The Regular Expression filter
        $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
        // Check if there is a url in the text
        if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
            // make the urls hyper links            
            foreach($url[0] as $v){                
                //current position of the searached url
                $curpos = strpos($text,' '.$v)+1;
                //delete the url                
                $text = substr_replace($text,'', $curpos, strlen($v));
                //insert the link
                $text = substr_replace($text,''.$v.'', $curpos ,0);                
            }
            return $text;
        } 
        else {
            // if no urls in the text just return the text
            return $text;
        }
    }
```

one of them anyway is in the file includes/comment.php.  There are other functions in there that takes the thread_id and passes it through to the read.php page and shows the replies to the thread.  Now on the read.php file I have this code:

```
<div id="comments">
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
<div class="comment" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
<div class="author">
<a href='profile.php?id=<?php echo $diuser[0] ?> '><?php echo htmlentities($comment->author) ?></a> wrote:
</div>
<div class="body">
<?php echo strip_tags($comment->body, '<strong><em><p><a><img>'); ?>
</div>
<div class="meta-info" style="font-size: 0.8em;">
<?php echo datetime_to_text($comment->posted); ?>
</div>
____________________________
</div>
<?php endforeach;
if(empty($comments)) { echo "No comments."; } ?>
</div>
```

I then changed that to call the new function I added:

```
<div id="comments">
<?php foreach($comments as $comment): ?>
<div class="comment" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
<div class="author">
<a href='profile.php?id=<?php echo $diuser[0] ?> '><?php echo htmlentities($comment->author) ?></a> wrote:
</div>
<div class="body">

<?php $comment_body = Comment::url_to_link($comment->body);
     echo nl2br($comment_body); ?>
</div>
<div class="meta-info" style="font-size: 0.8em;">
<?php echo datetime_to_text($comment->posted); ?>
</div>
____________________________
</div>
```

This produces something that looks like this:

```
user wrote:
Thttp://www.example.com

Testing links.
June 28, 2013 at 03:09 PM
____________________________
```

The data should be showing up as

```
user wrote:
Testing

http://www.example.com

Testing Links.
Date (you get the idea)
```

So the code is doing something, but it's not changing the data into a link it's just removing some of the data and then slapping it together.  I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Yes I have used htmlentities and mysql_real_escape_string.  Please help me.

--EDIT--

tl;dr = user inputs the following into the forum:

```
testing http://stackoverflow.com  testing links
```

I want the link to work on output but I only want the actual link to show up as a link; it should look like this

```
testing <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</a> testing links
```

But the code that I've found doesn't work.  Do I have to add a input for links to get this to work, I can do that, but I would much rather a user just type in the url in the body input and then the code will transform it into an actual link on output.  The code that I currently have is above, again it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://regexr.com?35d3g

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be looking at MySQL. The database is fine.

What you need to look at is regular expressions and other text parsing functionality to search the comment for links and then output it surrounded by tags:

It's reasonably straightforward. However, it's not trivial and the practical upshot of it is that most websites just use BBCode or invent a simple syntax (StackOverflow and Reddit both use combinations of brackets surround links (although StackOverflow also detects links)).

`preg_replace` probably does what you're looking for.

Please re-write your long spiel to condense it to contain:

- The actual text you are processing
- The intended output (with HTML characters)

Remove any reference to databases. You've already got the data out from the database, the source of the information is now irrelevant.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment then an answer.

Comment: @DavidStarkey 99% of the post was irrelevant waffle.  "I just need it to search the body data find the link turn it into a link and then spit it out with everything around it." I think I gave a response on how to do that, and some advice on writing better SO questions. In contrast, your comment sounds like an answer to me!

Comment: Maybe it is an answer but as you noted, question was entirely too long so TL;DR there.  I have a personal policy that if I don't read the whole question I don't post an answer, but comments are always helpful.  Feel free to use that Regex fiddle if you think it helps answer the question.

Comment: I've edited the question.  I have added a few lines for the tl;dr people out there.  But my question was not answered.  I've tried preg_replace but that still didn't do what I wanted it to do, maybe my code wasn't right.  I will look into it more, but my problem is that when users enter url's the links don't work when viewers click on the link in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update this so others will know how to get this to work, since I didn't get any real help before.

First I'm using PHP OO methods.

Example:

```
Comment.php  // has the makeLinks code

public static function makeLinks($str) {    
     return preg_replace('/(https?):\/\/([A-Za-z0-9\._\-\/\?=&;%,]+)/i', '<a href="$1://$2" target="_blank">$1://$2</a>', $str);
}
```

that function would be called within the other files that needs the makeLinks command and that would look like this:

```
$comment_body = Comment::makeLinks(strip_tags($comment->body, '<strong><em><p><a><img>'));
     echo nl2br($comment_body);
```

I hope that makes sense and that someone can find it useful.